# Using browserHistory in react-router instead of hashHistory breaks my page loading

Tags: react-router

When I change this line `<Router history={hashHistory}>` to `<Router history={browserHistory}>`,  in

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={M}/>
      <Route path="/a" component={A}/>
      <Route path="/b" component={B}/>
      <Route path="/c" component={C}/>
      <Route path="/d" component={D}/>
</Router>,
```

my pages stop loading. I get this error `Warning: [react-router] Location "/dist/index.html#/b?_k=xm0tin" did not match any routes`.
Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption here, but if you are going through the samples on the web and are using webpack, you need to do a couple of things (I have run into the same problem as well while learning this)

In your webpack.config.js add this:

```
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
```

Here's a ticket that will explain why this is needed: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/676

And then you need to make sure that your consolidated js file (bundle.js typically) is referenced correctly in the index.html file, like below:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Note the / before bundle.js